# Mind helping on Prolog programming?

Tags: prolog

OK. This is the second time I post this question, the last time my question was closed by few admins because as they say "I didn't do enough effort to solve it first" so now I solved about 70% of it. And I hope this time someone can give me an answer that completes my code.

This question was given to me as an assignment on a ( Prolog language Programming ) .

1. Job assignment. N jobs are to be done using N different machine. The cost of using
   machine i to do the job j are given in the following table.

   ```
                  1  2  3  4
                 ____________
               1| 6  5  3  6
               2| 5  6  8  12
               3| 8  6  8  9
               4| 3  6  5  8
   ```

\\ The upper ( 1 2 3 4 ) belong to (Jobs) category

\\ The left side ( 1 2 3 4 ) belong to ( Machines ) category

Write a declarative Prolog program to determine which jobs should be assigned to which
machines in order to minimize the total cost.

The first step that I did is I picked the lowest value number from the first vertical line of(Jobs) and subtracted it on all the rest numbers in the same line ( 3-8 ) , ( 3-6 ) , ( 3 - 5 ) ... and so on for the rest of the vertical lines .

This is my code ( it's not yet complete , so basically I'm looking for someone who can complete it before next Monday morning 23 Dec ) .

```
 >> initial:- M1=[6,5,3,6],
          M2=[5,6,8,12],
          M3=[8,6,8,9],
          M4=[3,6,5,8],

          write('M1= ['),
          printlist(M1),
      write('M2= ['),
          printlist(M2),
      write('M3= ['),
          printlist(M3),
      write('M4= ['),
          printlist(M4),nl,nl,

      redrow(M1,L1),
      redrow(M2,L2),
      redrow(M3,L3),
      redrow(M4,L4),

      write('L1= ['),
          printlist(L1),
      write('L2= ['),
          printlist(L2),
      write('L3= ['),
          printlist(L3),
      write('L4= ['),
          printlist(L4),nl,nl,

      /*Lc1=[],
      Lc2=[],
      Lc3=[],
      Lc4=[],*/

      col1(L1,L2,L3,L4,Lc1),
      col2(L1,L2,L3,L4,Lc2),
      col3(L1,L2,L3,L4,Lc3),
      col4(L1,L2,L3,L4,Lc4),          

      write('Lc1= ['),
          printlist(Lc1),
      write('Lc2= ['),
          printlist(Lc2),
      write('Lc3= ['),
          printlist(Lc3),
      write('Lc4= ['),
          printlist(Lc4),nl,nl,

      redrow(Lc1,Lx1),
      redrow(Lc2,Lx2),
      redrow(Lc3,Lx3),
      redrow(Lc4,Lx4),

      write('Lx1= ['),
          printlist(Lx1),
      write('Lx2= ['),
          printlist(Lx2),
      write('Lx3= ['),
          printlist(Lx3),
      write('Lx4= ['),
          printlist(Lx4),nl,nl,

      col1(Lx1,Lx2,Lx3,Lx4,Ly1),
      col2(Lx1,Lx2,Lx3,Lx4,Ly2),
      col3(Lx1,Lx2,Lx3,Lx4,Ly3),
      col4(Lx1,Lx2,Lx3,Lx4,Ly4),

      write('Ly1= ['),
          printlist(Ly1),
      write('Ly2= ['),
          printlist(Ly2),
      write('Ly3= ['),
          printlist(Ly3),
      write('Ly4= ['),
          printlist(Ly4),nl,nl.

redrow(M1,L1):- minimo(M1,Min), redcopy(M1,L1,Min).

minimo([X], X) :- !.
minimo([X,Y|Tail], N):-
    ( X > Y ->
        minimo([Y|Tail], N)
    ;
        minimo([X|Tail], N)
    ).



min1(X,Y,X):- X<Y, write('in min1 X= '), write(X), nl.
min1(X,Y,Y):- X>Y,write('in min1 Y= '), write(Y), nl.
min1(X,Y,Y).

redcopy(L,R,V) :- accCp(L,R,V).
accCp([],[],_).
accCp([H|T1],[M|T2],V) :- M is H-V, accCp(T1,T2,V).

col1([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H3|T3],[H4|T4],[H1,H2,H3,H4]).
col2([H11,H12|T1],[H21,H22|T2],[H31,H32|T3],[H41,H42|T4],[H12,H22,H32,H42]).
col3([H11,H12,H13|T1],[H21,H22,H23|T2],[H31,H32,H33|T3],[H41,H42,H43|T4],[H13,H23,H33,H43]).
col4([H11,H12,H13,H14|T1],[H21,H22,H23,H24|T2],[H31,H32,H33,H34|T3],[H41,H42,H43,H44|T4],[H14,H24,H34,H44]).

/*redcopy([],[],_).
redcopy(Ls,Ld,R):- Ls=[X|Lst],Ld=[X-R|Ld], redcopy(Lst,Ld,R).*/

printlist([]):- write(']'),nl.
printlist(L):- L=[X|Lt], write(X), write(' , '), printlist(Lt).
```

---

And I need to know at the end what question to ask the computer to give me an output of ( Yes , No ). Thank You in advance .

Note : if my code or the question was not clear ( ask me to clear it to you ) don't close my question , because there might be someone who already got an answer for it .

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? *so basically im looking for someone who can complete it before next monday morning* is a very poor start here.

Comment: What is preventing you from making progress?

Comment: ok .. my bad , this is what i really need " determine which jobs should be assigned to which machines in order to minimize the total cost." , so basically i want an output from my codes that minimize the total cost .

Comment: i actually don't quite know .. at first i thought this should give me an output but i only get an error .. so i thought there should be some swapping between all the 4 (cols) and (mins) and do another calculations perhaps ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this is what i get every time i load my .pl file : ! Error 43 : End Of File

!   Error : 43 End of file
!   | printlist(L):- L=[X|Lt], write(X), write(' , '), printlist(Lt).

Comment: can you try to save the codes in any notepad then open it on the prolog program to test it ?

Comment: ok now i got this new Error : Error 20 Predicate not defined

Comment: already did .. still not working :(

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the answer you require, because doesn't try to fulfill the 30% hypothetically missing. Really, if you could explain how such bold statement

> i solved about 70% of it ..

can be evaluated, we all could learn something from your assignment. But alas, your code seems so far from any 'declarative style' solution. *Where* do you *declare* how to solve the problem ?

Let's start from high level description:

> determine which jobs should be assigned to which machines in order to minimize the total cost

then a *reusable* solution could be sketched:

```
assign_jobs_min_cost :-
    MJC =  % machines,jobs,cost
    [[6, 5, 3, 6 ],
     [5, 6, 8, 12],
     [8, 6, 8, 9 ],
     [3, 6, 5, 8 ]],
    assign_jobs_min_cost(MJC, Jobs, Cost),
    writeln(Jobs:Cost).
```

an *assignment of jobs* could be seen simply as a permutation of indexes (thanks to friendly presentation of problem data), then

```
assign_jobs_min_cost(MJC, Jobs, Cost) :-
    aggregate_all(min(C, P),
              (permutation([1, 2, 3, 4], P),
               cost_assign(MJC, P, C)),
              min(Cost, Jobs)).
```

You see, Prolog, as any other language, come with a *library*, that defines the *idiomatic* ways to solve problems. Learning how to use a library it's often the *biggest* part of language apprenticeship.

Here I use SWI-Prolog library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29)), as well as [permutation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2)/2. Depending on *your* Prolog (and your examinator requirements), you could try to replace such calls with your own definitions.

Now we are left with just `cost_assign(MJC, Jobs, Cost)` to compute. Again using library constructs, it's a 'single statement':

```
cost_assign(MJC, Jobs, Cost) :-
    aggregate_all(
        sum(C),
        (between(1, 4, Mac),
         nth1(Mac, MJC, RowC),
         nth1(Mac, Jobs, J),
         nth1(J, RowC, C)
        ), Cost)
    % uncomment  below to see all assignments
    %,writeln(Jobs:Cost).
    .
```

but you'll learn much more writing your own...

Comment: Hey CapelliC .. thank you very much for the help .. your code is simple and straight forward unlike mine XD .. but i still cant figure out what question to ask prolog after saving this code to the program .. i came with this :  total_cost(X). ?

Comment: I enter `?- assign_jobs_min_cost.` in console to see the result, with SWI-Prolog.

Comment: oh so it doesnt work on win-prolog 4.94 ?

Comment: Sorry, not really, and I don't have win-prolog available. Those libraries are fairly complex, but see if you can figure out what's going on, at logical level.

Comment: i cant thank you enough .. you just saved my life big time .. this is what i got for the output : [3,2,4,1]:21 .. so the code finally worked , i'll try to study your code and learn more about prolog for future uses .. thanks again :):):)

Comment: Do you know about select/3 ? permutation can be implemented with that.

Comment: never heard of it . sounds interesting though .

Comment: I don't think permutations are needed for this problem. Combination of select/3 and nth1/3 does the trick.